# Delete a windows service from offline wim?

Tags: wds, wim

I have WIM files in Windows Deployment Services with various images for computers.  Unfortunately, I'm not using MDT or system center or anything automated to create these images - just installed on a computer, customized, syspreped and captured an image.  One day I'll improve that process, but not today.

Using DISM I can add drivers and files and such.  But what I really need to one of them is remove a windows service that is causing problems.  I'd love to be able to do it without going through sysprepping and recapturing the image.

On a live windows install, I'd just run "sc delete servicename".  Is there way I can do the equivalent on a mounted WIM image?

Comment: dism supports removing roles i think, its been awhile since I've used dism. If not you can mount the wim then regedit the service entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd mount the wim file via dism then use regedit to load the system key then remove the service.

Comment: I second that, it should work. You can edit the registry of wim files.